# want to fetch conditional data using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

My Working scenario is, i have 4 types of Pen 
1-Diamond
2-Gold
3- Bronze
4- Silver

i want when someone select Diamond Pen on the bottom input he will type quantity so if he select 1-Diamond Pen so the amount should be vary with each other, on the same way all 4 types pen rates should be vary.

My Code is

ajax.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<!-- <input type="text" name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)"> -->
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="1">Diamond</option>
<option value="2">Gold</option>
<option value="3">Bronze</option>
<option value="4">Silver</option>
</select>
<!-- <input type="submit" name="users"> -->

</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

getuser.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','fm_all');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT * FROM all_company WHERE id = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Hometown</th>
<th>Job</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['city'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['province'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is only Drop Box value is working, i do not know how to attach input quantity box with it. please help.

Note: this code is working according to id when i select drop box value so it show according to id but i did not attach it with quantity.

Comment: And what is the problem? Add new `<input>`?

Comment: now drop box working, i want to join one input box with it for quantity, but the problem is i do not know how to join it

Comment: `"getuser.php?q="+str+"&quanity="+qty`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by following way in case you don't want for perform any operation on form submit

call **showUser()** on onkeyup for input and provide it some id may be quantity
call **showUser()** on onchange for select box and also provide it some id can be pen

```
function showUser(){
    quantity = $("#quantity").val();
    selected_pen = $("#pen").val();
    if (quantity != null && selected_pen != null && typeof(quantity) !='undefined'){
        your ajax calling code
    }
}
```

you can call above function **onchange** for select box and on **onkeyup** in input textbox. But with above mentioned way it will call ajax every time there is change in your text field or select box.